# Is there any tool to decompile java code for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

As we all know,.net provides tools like Telerik decompile,reflector and much more for "reflector" C# code,even the Visual Studio tools IL.
So how can I watch my java code in eclipse?
thanks.

Comment: Please read the site's help link to see what questions are appropriate for this site.

Comment: Google JD-Eclipse http://jd.benow.ca/ screenshot: http://jd.benow.ca/img/screenshot8.png

Comment: [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) & [Attaching source code in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1157618/1060037)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jd-gui(jar java).exe](http://jd.benow.ca/) which will decompile about 95%.According to my usage.

You can see the Source code of your class.