# Eclipse - Unable to install breakpoint in a Java API Class

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have found a few question about the issue here on StackOverlow, but all were about own written code. My problem is a bit different, because I want to debug a Java API class, named `javax.swing.JComponent`.

My first problem was, that I couldn't see any sources. I fixed it described like here [Attach the Java Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157597/attach-the-java-source-code) by attaching the source to `rt.jar`.

Now I see the source and I want to set a breakpoint in the `JComponent` class. If I try so, I get the error message:

[image: error message]

"Modify compiler options to generate line number attributes". That is a nice proposal. But my JDK version was already compiled when I downloaded it..

So, do I have it to compile on my own? Or do you have other advices?

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: I have installed
- Eclipse Neon
- jdk1.8.0_91
- Windows 10 (64 Bit)

Answer (score 1):

One probable issue could come from your application server in IDE pointing to JRE instead of JDK.

Try verifying:

> Window -> Preferences --> Server --> runtime environments
>
> <Your-Application-Server> --> edit
>
> Select a JDK instead of JRE

Not sure if you have gone through this link.... has few solutions which worked for some.

[Eclipse - Unable to install breakpoint due to missing line number attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes)

Comment: I don't use an application server.. So that couldn't be the solution, or am I wrong? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you use JRE on your build path in this case.
Try do this:

`Window -> Preferences --> Java --> Installed JRES-->then use jdk as default JRE`

problem fixed!

Comment: what does that have to do with compiler options?

Comment: @committedandroider did you checked [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)